# internationalization with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

I'm trying to make a simple internationalization by replacing strings of text and I have developed the next code for it:

```
//INTERNACIONALIZACIÓN
$(function(){
    arrayCadenas = $(".texts").text(); // make an array of strings to translate

    var es_ES = ["Federación de reinserción1", "NOSOTROS", "QUIENES SOMOS", "QUE HACEMOS",      "PROYECTOS", "SGU-UPD SARTU II", "RED INCORPORA", "APRENDIZAJE", "CONTACTO"];
    var eu_EU = ["Federación de reinserción2", "GUK", "NORK GARA", "ZER EGIN", "PROIEKTUAK", "SGU-UPD SARTU II", "RED INCORPORA", "APRENDIZAJE", "KONTAKTUA"];
    var en_EN = ["Federación de reinserción3", "NOSOTROS", "QUIENES SOMOS", "QUE HACEMOS", "PROYECTOS", "SGU-UPD SARTU II", "RED INCORPORA", "APRENDIZAJE", "CONTACTO"];
    languages = [es_ES, eu_EU, en_EN];

    $(".lang").each(function(i, lis){ 
        $(this).on("click", function(e){
            e.stopPropagation;
        select = languages[i];
        console.log(arrayCadenas);
        console.log(languages[i]);

        arrayCadenas.each(function(j, cadena){ 
             cadena.text(languages[i][j]); 
        });
        });
    }); 
});
```

When I click on a flag, in console I got this:

[17:53:04.223] TypeError: arrayCadenas.each is not a function @ file:///var/www/TRABAJOS/SARTUWEB/%2806-08-2013%29%20sartutheme7/index.html:253
[17:53:04.222] Federación de reinserciónNOSOTROSQUIENES SOMOSQUE HACEMOSPROYECTOSSGU-UPD SARTU IIRED INCORPORAAPRENDIZAJECONTACTO
[17:53:04.222] ["Federaci\xF3n de reinserci\xF3n3", "NOSOTROS", "QUIENES SOMOS", "QUE HACEMOS", "PROYECTOS", "SGU-UPD SARTU II", "RED INCORPORA", "APRENDIZAJE", "CONTACTO"]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
//...
arrayCadenas = $(".texts");
//...
console.log(arrayCadenas.text());
//...
```

You are reading the inner text which does not have an each function. Read the objects instead.

Comment: I am glad your problem was solved. If my answer was helpful for you, then please, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Lajos Arpad. i was thinking about it and finally I solved it.
In the second each, where it says:

```
    arrayCadenas.each(function(j, cadena){ 
        cadena.text(languages[i][j]); 
    });
```

I replace "cadena" by "$(this)", so the final code looks like this:

```
    arrayCadenas.each(function(j, cadena){ 
        $(this).text(languages[i][j]); 
    });
```

As a final comment, you can replace "$(this)" by "$(cadena)", bacause both of them references to the current item.
Thanks again.